# GraphQL with RESTful returning empty response

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

I am connecting `GraphQL` with `REST` endpoints, I confirmed that whenever I am calling `http://localhost:3001/graphql` it is hitting `REST` endpoint and it is returning `JSON` response to `GraphQL` server, but I am getting an empty response from `GraphQL` server to `GUI` as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "merchant": {
      "id": null
    }
  }
}
```

Query (decoded manually):

```
http://localhost:3001/graphql?query={
  merchant(id: 1) {
    id
  }
}
```

Below is how my `GraphQLObjectType` looks like:

```
const MerchantType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Merchant',
  description: 'Merchant details',
  fields : () => ({
    id : {
      type: GraphQLString // ,
      // resolve: merchant => merchant.id
    },
    email: {type: GraphQLString}, // same name as field in REST response, so resolver is not requested
    mobile: {type: GraphQLString}
  })
});


const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'The root of all... queries',
  fields: () => ({
    merchant: {
      type: merchant.MerchantType,
      args: {
        id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
      },
      resolve: (root, args) => rest.fetchResponseByURL(`merchant/${args.id}/`)
    },
  }),
});
```

Response from `REST` endpoint (I also tried with single object in JSON instead of JSON array):

```
[
  {
    "merchant": {
      "id": "1",
      "email": "a@b.com",
      "mobile": "1234567890"
    }
  }
]
```

REST call using `node-fetch`

```
function fetchResponseByURL(relativeURL) {

  return fetch(`${config.BASE_URL}${relativeURL}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
  })
  .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });

}

const rest = {
  fetchResponseByURL
}

export default rest
```

GitHub: https://github.com/vishrantgupta/graphql 
JSON endpoint (dummy): https://api.myjson.com/bins/8lwqk

*Edit:* Adding `node.js` tag, may be issue with promise object.

Comment: There's probably a mismatch between the shape of the response from the REST endpoint and your schema. Can you update your question to include the full response from the REST endpoint?

Comment: thanks @DanielRearden for checking this out. I have updated my question with endpoint response.

Comment: what is `rest` in `resolve: (root, args) => rest.fetchResponseByURL(`merchant/${args.id}/`)` ?

Comment: that is an export from other js file `export default rest` this have a REST `fetch` `fetchResponseByURL` method

Comment: @xadm I have updated my question with that details

Comment: return promise?

Comment: https://kevincoletta.com/2016/01/21/graphql-resolve-returns-null-values/ - maybe it's related

Comment: Your REST endpoint seems to respond with an array but your field expects an object. The array then obviously has no property `id`. To fix this maybe return the first element or use `.then(ms => ms.find(m => m.id === args.id))`. Furthermore I would suggest to remove the `catch` handler in the fetch function since it will turn the promise into a resolved promise with value `undefined`. It is better to let it go through to the GraphQL resolve (at least in development).

Comment: @Herku I have tried by returning just a single json object instead of array but the issue is still same. I have created a github repo https://github.com/vishrantgupta/graphql and using a dummy `JSON` service https://api.myjson.com/bins/8lwqk

Comment: @xadm I tried the solution given in that link, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **fetchResponseByURL** function get empty string.

I think the main problem is that you are using wrong function to get the your JSON string, please try to install **request-promise** and use it to get your JSON string.

https://github.com/request/request-promise#readme

something like

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
function fetchResponseByURL(relativeURL) {
  return rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/8lwqk')
    .then((html) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(html)
      return data.merchant
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  // .catch(error => { console.log('request failed', error); });

}
```

Comment: I implemented `request-promise` but still the same result. I cross verified if I am getting an empty JSON response from REST endpoint but that is not the case. I have shared the execution of this flow https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aZkw66S7JUO4wYxnDL-rUiWwm5Dnho8l

Comment: I don't know what's your requirements. Do you store all your data in JSON with the link 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/8lwqk'? And you want to get the specific merchant info by id?

Comment: It will be a link from like how I posted above and response `Content-Type application/json`

Comment: I have updated code, try to use the fetchResponseByURL function in my answer

Comment: graphql's resolver, it will auto match the object field. So you should return the merchant object at the end of resolver. Then it can filter the fields which you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case using `data.merchant` solved my problem. But the above suggested solution i.e., use of `JSON.parse(...)` might not be the best practice because if there are no object in JSON, then expected response might be as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "merchant": null
  }
}
```

Instead of fields to be `null`.

```
{
  "data": {
    "merchant": {
      "id": null // even though merchant is null in JSON, 
                 // I am getting a merchant object in response from GraphQL
    }
  }
}
```

I have updated my GitHub: https://github.com/vishrantgupta/graphql with working code.